# Swift: Replace TextField number separator dot with comma

Tags: swiftui, number-formatting

I have a TextField:

```
struct DecimalKeyboardView: View {
@Binding var value: Double
var placeholder: String
var formatter: NumberFormatter

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        TextField(placeholder, value: $value, formatter: formatter)
        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to force the TextField entry of a "." to be a ",", because in some regions the numPad has the separator ".".

E.G. input: 23.3 should be 23,3

I tried the following:

```
struct NumForm {

// Currency format (VALUE)
static let formatterCurr: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
    formatter.groupingSeparator = "."
    formatter.zeroSymbol = ""
    return formatter
}()
}
```

But the keyboard input of 23.3 gets formatted into 23,0.

Is there a possibility to force the devices locale to a specific country so the keyboard displays only the separator "," or is there a possibility to format the textfield input differently?

Comment: But why? If the user has a locale with dot as the separator then formatting it using a comma will only be confusing (and might lead to other issues)

Comment: Please, do not do this. Allow the entry and formatting to be appropriate to the user's locale.

Comment: Your code is SwiftUI. You should add that tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your formatter to the formatter defined in the view:

```
struct DecimalKeyboardView: View {
    
    @Binding var value: Double
    
    var placeholder: String = ""
    
    // Static constant, since we don't need to recreate it every time view is recreated. 
    static let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
        formatter.groupingSeparator = "."
        formatter.zeroSymbol = ""
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TextField(placeholder, value: $value, formatter: Self.formatter)
    // ...
```

And the caller of course must have a matching state:

```
   // ...
   @State var value: Double = 2.23
    
    var body: some View {
        DecimalKeyboardView(value: $value)
    // ...
```

And it will work (the above for example will show `2,23` for me, even though in my locale the decimal separator is `.`.

However. For many people `,` *is a grouping separator*, and they are unfamiliar with it being a decimal separator. In my area, for example, if people see `2,23` they will think that it's an incorrect usage of grouping (thousands) separator, and will interpret the whole number as "two hundred twenty three".

So overriding the locale settings like this is generally a bad idea. My recommendation is: format your number the way you want in terms of decimal points. But leave the locale for iOS to set.

Comment: I see your point. Thank you for your answer. For me it works to display the number correctly formatted in the textfield: e.g. 31.322,34. But when I enter a new number with the decimalPad (which has a "." as a separator) the dot isn't recognized as a separator. So everything after typing "." is just 0. e.g. typing 34.5 turns into 34,00 although the number ist formatted correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's yet another reason to not force format change for current locale. Once `.` is not a decimal separator, typing `12.34` creates a number `12` since dot is not valid at that point, and everything after it is ignored. And typing `123.456` is `123456`. So you can do one of 2 things: 1 - use alphanumeric or custom keyboard where you allow to type `,` and not `.` for decimal separator. 2 - make field bind to `String` internally (that way you can format it any way you want), and then only convert it to binding number when user finished changing the field.

Comment: Again, the right choice IMO is let it be `.` for locales with dot, and `,` for locales with comma